# Rails Database Migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a previously defined database to which I want to use Ruby on Rails as my front end to. Are there any steps in the Rails Migration process that can make this process faster or am I stuck interpreting the schema and building the migration and classes by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There's a quite [simple solution](http://www.justinball.com/2008/05/09/dump-an-existing-database-schema-into-a-ruby-on-rails-migration-ready-format/), actually :)